# Catch Volley exception during request queue add

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I can't catch exception or get any error description if URI passed is incorrect.

`requestQueue.add(request)` just pass silently. But error logs contaings something like:

```
E/Volley: [1045] NetworkDispatcher.processRequest: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL ?action=login&login=XX&mpassword=XX
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL ?action=login&login=XX&mpassword=XX
          at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:171)
          at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:120)
          at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:87)
       Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ?action=login&login=XX&mpassword=XX
          at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:589)
          at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:486)
          at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:435)
          at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:92)
          at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:131)
          at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:120) 
          at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:87)
```

How to catch this error?

Please note, that neither `onResponse(JSONObject response)`, nor `onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)` fired.

**Update:**
I think it is a bug of Volley. It executes silently (no error callback and no success callback). Also no error at queue add (when error actually happens according to logs).
So probably, more correct question will be:

**Why exception not bulbs up in any way? Do I missed some callback or params check needed by design?**

I expect to know if request succeeded.
I expect incorrect input params should raise exception but not be executed silently.
I expect to have no sanity checks before calling Volley code. No protocol, no server name pattern, no port notation, no inline password/username checks, etc. I should not to care about this, because Volley should handle higher level of code.

Comment: i think you forget to add base url with volley request.

Comment: Can you share your code

Comment: *No protocol* and *Bad URL* is pretty obvious, isn't it?

Comment: Sure error is obvious. I need no error explanation. It is only test case. But I l do not control input of URI and I do not know how to catch error from Volley code. It just passes silently. See my explanation, please.

Answer (score 0):

its clearly said here that

Bad URL ?action=login&login=XX&mpassword=XX

it means that either you are not using protocols in the url which are a little necessary to some extent so please do something like this in the URL

http://yourUrl.com?action=login&login=XX&mpassword=XX

Incase if the uri is coming remotely try something like this

```
String incomingUrl = your_incoming_url;
if(incomingUrl.contains("http://")||incomingUrl.contains("https://")){
//use that incoming url in the volley url area
}else{

String httpString = "http://"+incomingURl;

//and use new httpString at the url of volley 

}
```

that's a fix for the issue I guess

Comment: Sure. I see this. I need not explanation of this test case error. I need the receipt of how to catch it in code. Currently it passes silently.

Comment: well check the URI then if it has any protocol in it then its ok else add it using concat property of String and then use that newly made String in URL